# Can I run MONGODB on my Mac OSX 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, mongodb, mean-stack

I am trying to install a MEAN stack (I don't even really know what that MEANS!) but am Just wondering if there are any limitations in terms of hardware on my somewhat outdated machine.  I wish there was a way to install a newer mac os version on my laptop because it still seems to work good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Mongo supports](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) OS X 10.6 and up.  Mongo likes to use  a lot of memory.  While technically it should run, it's probably not going to be a good time.